# Issue writing on a file from variable in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm having some issues while trying to copy content of a variable into a file:

```
echo "$template" >> "debug.conf"
```

if I check the content of debug.conf it's empty.

$template variable is populated with the following code:

```
template="$(cat /home/scripts/debug-template)"
```

and debug-template file content is:

```
cat debug-template 

Enabled=1
OfflReboot=1
HOFailBB=1
OfflineBB=1
AcuPcapSize=20
RngRspBB=1
T4TimeBB=1
MaxBbTarballs=50 
MaxPcapTarBalls=100
tcpdump() {
command tcpdump $@ 'udp or tcp'
}
```

the command is executed as a root so there aren't permission issues.

Anyone could help me to figure out what could be causing the problem?

Thanks for your precious help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the quotation

```
echo $template >> debug.conf
```

Comment: Done! now debug.conf contain only the first row of debug template. any idea ?

Comment: cat debug.conf

Enabled=1

Comment: The quotes are not the problem. Double-quotes around the variable are needed to preserve whitespace (mainly linefeeds); quotes around the filename aren't needed, but don't cause any trouble either.

Comment: I am using *zsh* and it works fine, with this command. Can you check if the variable has all the file content first? @paolo9785

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler to just run:

```
cp /home/scripts/debug-template debug.conf
```

Comment: no i can't because debug-template and debug.conf are not in the same machines and I don't want to use scp to copy file since there isn't rsa key authentication so I should use clear password in the script

Comment: If *debug.conf* is supposed to be output to another machine, this should be noted in the question.  There's no password in *debug-template*.

Comment: @paolo9785 If the files are on different machines, then you must be defining and using the `template` variable on different machines, in which case *that* is almost certainly the problem. You need to edit the question to clarify what's happening on what computer, over what kind of connection, etc. As is, the question is missing critical information.

Answer (score 0):

Hi your problem is with double quotation in right hand side of your expression correct it like below:-

Also first check whether `template` has any information on it or not

```
echo "$template"
echo "$template" >> debug.conf
```